# Zend Framework: How to UNION two different database table

Tags: zend-framework

I am new in Zend Framework. I have to make query by joining two database table in Zend Framework. Here is the code :

```
Select 'DB1',Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4 FROM DB1.Table where condition='20' 
UNION 
Select 'DB2',Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4 FROM DB2.Table where condition='0' LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Do you want to do this in Zend Framework 1 or Zend Framework 2?

Comment: I am using Zend Framework 1.12 version

Comment: Did you have a look at this?: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.union

Comment: use two models, then use their dbAdapters, make two queries, union the two arrays